# How to create object fields from array content using JQ

Tags: json, jq

I have following object:

```
{
  "base": "/templates",
  "title": "Templates",
  "categories": {
    "category1": {
      "propertiesResources": {
        "resources": {
          "cliTemplate": {
            "type": "CLIENT",
            "path": "properties/cli.json",
            "roles": [
              "ROLE_SYSTEM_READ",
              "ROLE_SYSTEM_WRITE"
            ]
          },
          "viewerTemplate": {
            "type": "SERVER",
            "path": "properties/server.json",
            "roles": [
              "ROLE_CONFIGURATOR_READ",
              "ROLE_CONFIGURATOR_WRITE"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see the field roles is an array which contains list of roles. The roles are guaranteed to be in this order. What I need is to replace the field `roles` with two new fields: `roleRead` and `roleWrite` where this new fields will have corresponding values from the array.

```
{
  "base": "/templates",
  "title": "Templates",
  "categories": {
    "category1": {
      "propertiesResources": {
        "resources": {
          "cliTemplate": {
            "type": "CLIENT",
            "path": "properties/cli.json",
            "readRole": "ROLE_SYSTEM_READ",
            "writeRole": "ROLE_SYSTEM_WRITE"
          },
          "viewerTemplate": {
            "type": "SERVER",
            "path": "properties/server.json",
            "readRole": "ROLE_CONFIGURATOR_READ",
            "writeRole": "ROLE_CONFIGURATOR_WRITE"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Using this command I was able to get half way there

```
.categories[][].resources[].roles|={"readRole": .[0], "writeRole": .[1]}
```

https://jqplay.org/s/QPRMdXR0Os

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to add the objects together with the `.roles` array and delete it after

```
.categories[][].resources[] |= ( 
  . + { readRole: .roles[0], writeRole: .roles[1] } | del(.roles)
)
```

<sup>[jqplay demo](https://jqplay.org/s/y7oeIHNRoZ)</sup>